# Cors blocks specified origin?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, cors

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import blogRouter from './routes/blog';
import { tokenAuth } from './middleware/tokenAuth';

dotenv.config();

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT ?? 8000;

interface CustomRequest extends Request {
  user?: any;
}
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(`/blog`, blogRouter);

app.use(tokenAuth);

app.post('/', async (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {
  try {
    res.send('gucci');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is my express typescript server on port 8000.

```
const post_dummy = async () => {
    console.log('called');
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        '/',
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          withCredentials: true // Send cookies with credentials
        }
      );

      console.log('POST request successful:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error making POST request:', error);
    }
  };
```

This is a function in my React client(Port 5173), where i try to call an endpoint with a jwt stored in httponly cookie.

But I get this:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Since I specified the origin I was expecting things to work out fine but they didn't and I can't seem to figure it out why.

I'd like to mention that if I use a jwt not stored in httponly cookie everything works.